# Material-ui components do not display correctly on production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI in my React project and while in local everything seems to work perfectly, but when I deploy to firebase those same MUI components do not display correctly.

I was thinking maybe there is an issue of compatibility between firebase and Material UI but don't know where to start to solve this problem !

Anyone had the same issue ?

Local
[image: local]

Production
[image: production]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem !

Apparently, I was using wrong MUI component customization.

I was trying to give my personal touch to some of the components that I imported from MUI library, but I was using "Global css" for modifications, which is wrong.

NOT GOOD

```
.MuiButtonBase-root {
 color: red
}
```

It is possible to use this way to style MUI components but only on dev environment !
Also, it is recommanded to use MUI style customization methods [How to costumise - MUI](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/)